# What is the meaning of 「隣のおじいさんは言いました」

Tags: translation, meaning

I am reading 「花咲かじいさん」and there is a phrase used a lot like...

> 隣のおじいさんは言いました。

I have not seen this before and it doesn’t make sense to me from my understanding of 隣 meaning “next to”.

What does it mean here? Is it like a temporal “next”. Like... “Then the old man said...”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, doesn't mean "then" or "next" in a temporal sense. Depending on the context, the phrase you have quoted means either "the elderly man next to [someone]" or "the elderly man who lives [or lived] in the house next door."

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I completely didn’t realise it was talking about a different old man (the one who lives next door). Thanks! The story makes more sense now :-)

Comment: You're welcome – glad I could help!